# PHP - session file is missing after staring session

Tags: php, session

I start a session by using [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)() and I'm able to save data in `$_SESSION`. On a post back when I'm trying to retrieve data from session, `$_SESSION` data is NULL. I'm posting session id, then calling [session_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)(passsedSessionID) and then calling `session_start()` however the data in that session is gone. The session file that suppose to be written to [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) is not there.

My guess it has to do with session file not being written.

**update** figured out the problem. I didn't give php process write permissions to directory where I store session data. :-/

Comment: You normally do not need to call `session_id` to have sessions working with POST requests. You probably do some mistake with that, just noting.

Comment: when using sessions you just need to make sure session_start() is pretty much at the start of any page that will use sessions. no need to post id (best not to actually!).

Comment: If I don't pass session id and I don't call session_id(passsedsessionId) how do I know which session I need to work with? I might have hundreds of users with their own session. Passing session id lets me retrieve the right session for that user. No?

Comment: @dev.e.loper NO. `$_SESSION` variable returns data from **current user's** session.

Comment: @Brian, I'm calling session_start at start of the page that is using a session.

Comment: @loler  I know that. The question is how do you get current user's session? You need to have right session_id and call start_session with that session id.

Comment: Nope... The web-server & PHP already knows which session belongs to whom. Show us you're code where you're setting session data and then the page retrieving...

Comment: Sessions are usually perpetuated by cookies so you don't need to pass them via query string, in fact it's probably better that you don't.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `$_SESSION` global variable returns data only for **current user's** session, you don't need to pass `session_id` every time. And as @Brian mentioned in comments don't forget to ensure that `session_start()` is on the top of your code, then do not care about session identification.

OK, i hope this will make a sense for you. Try this code in different browsers and refresh page few times:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
?>
```

this will return session id and in different browser they will be different, but after page refresh they will stay the same.

Comment: "As long as $_SESSION global variable returns data for current user's session" <- how do you ensure that?  How do you know that session_start will start the right session?

Comment: You don't need to ensure it. If i access page `$_SESSION` will return my session and if you access the same page it will return your session.

Comment: I tried the code that doesn't call session_id() and it's not solving my original problem with retrieving session data. The session file is still not being written to disk.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are interpretting `session`  usage in different manner. You just need to call `session_start()` at the start of each page and this will synchronize the data between the pages.

#### page1.php

```
session_start()
-- store some session data
-- Some form with action page2.php
-- Submit button
```

#### page2.php

```
session_start()
-- fetch the session data
-- fetch the form data
```

Please take a look at this [coredogs tutorial](http://coredogs.com/lesson/php-sessions).

Hope this helps